# How to compile libruby with debugging symbols?

Tags: ruby

I am debugging a Perl extension that uses `libruby.so` (I am not familar with Ruby). On my Ubuntu laptop I can see the library is installed at: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-3.0.so.3.0`. I would like to recompile this library with `-g` option to include debugging symbols (such that I can step into function calls from a GDB session). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ruby from source and configuring with `--enable-shared` and `--enable-debug-env` gives me a `libruby.so` with debugging symbols:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev

# install other dependencies, see: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/contributing/building_ruby.md

$ wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.2/ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf ruby-3.2.2.tar.gz
$ cd ruby-3.2.2
$ ./configure --enable-shared --enable-debug-env optflags="-O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer" --prefix=/opt/ruby/3.2.2
$ make
$ sudo make install
# ... Now libruby is available in /opt/ruby/3.2.2/lib/libruby.so
```